# How to do redirect with ajax and django?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I have a form, which create new record in db. It works because of ajax. I have argument 'id', which is created automatically, when new record is being created (after fill form). I want to use this id, because I need to redirect users to page /127.0.0.1:8000/<id>, when they fill form or maybe simply print this link in page. How can I do this?

views.py

```py
def add_new(request):
    """ Function which upload new file to UploadModel. """

    form_upload = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='upload_form')
    if form_upload.is_valid() and request.is_ajax():
        new_file = form_upload.save(commit=False)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            new_file.author = request.user
        new_file.created_date = date.today()
        new_file.is_worked = True
        if new_file.ended_date <= date.today():
            new_file.is_worked = False
            new_file.delete()
        else:
            new_file.is_worked = True
        new_file.save()
        return redirect('index')
    form_upload = UploadForm()
    return render(request, 'sharing/index.html', {'form_upload': form_upload})
```

js file

```
function upload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: handleSuccess(),
    });
    return false;
}

function handleSuccess(){
    $("form")[0].reset();
    alert('Success uploading!');
    window.location.href = '/';

}

$(function() {
    $('form').submit(upload);
});
```

Comment: Why are you using Ajax at all if you want to redirect?

Comment: Can`t I do redirect with ajax? Can I print id of record with ajax?

Comment: You can not make redirection using AJAX code. Just send response link from django using JsonResponse class, and make redirection from client(javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def add_new(request):
    """ Function which upload new file to UploadModel. """

    form_upload = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='upload_form')
    if form_upload.is_valid() and request.is_ajax():
        new_file = form_upload.save(commit=False)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            new_file.author = request.user
        new_file.created_date = date.today()
        new_file.is_worked = True
        if new_file.ended_date <= date.today():
            new_file.is_worked = False
            new_file.delete()
        else:
            new_file.is_worked = True
        new_file.save()
        response_data = {}
        response_data['form_upload'] = UploadForm()
        return HttResponse(json.dumps(response_data),content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: The view sharing.views.add_new didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.